# Certificate request by PIN?

Tags: ssl, x509certificate, client-certificates

I am looking for certificate management based on PIN. The system I would like to have is this: I give my client a PIN (e.g., on a piece of label note) and he can use it as proof-of-identity to send request and acquire a certificate (preferably through HTTPS?). Where can I find more detailed information regarding this technique? So far, I've checked the RFC of CMS but there is no mentioning that you can use a PIN as proof-of-identity (only if the client has some type of certificate).

Thank you very much for the hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a PIN on a label, why not give your client a private key and certificate that you generate?  You can put them on a USB drive, or even a special USB token device where the private key cannot be extracted.  The client could then use that to connect to your service via 2-way SSL.

Comment: Well, I feel it might be a simple approach, for example, like guest visiting. I don't have to use any extra media except the network. I can implement it but this shouldn't be a new problem, right? If there is any available system/tool, that would be great.

Comment: You can use USB tokens like this [eToken](http://www.safenet-inc.com/products/data-protection/two-factor-authentication/etoken-pro/).  You can use [openssl](http://www.openssl.org/) to create a private/public keypair, corresponding certificate, and place them into a PKCS12 file that can be imported into the eToken.  The eToken comes with software drivers that allow browsers to interact with the eTokens just like they would with a PKCS12 file that you would import into the browser.

Comment: Thanks a lot. After I learn more about OpenSSL, maybe I could start with command line. But one thing I didn't find so far is how to send certificate request to a remote SSL server. Because if so, the remote admin can just sign it for me. And I can retrieve it later. I know how the retrieving part may work, but just don't know how to send the certificate request. Of course, I could use other media. But is it possible through ssl command line? Thanks.

Comment: As far as the request goes, you could set up a basic web service with an API that allows for sending the requests and receiving a response.

Comment: Cool, that should be doable. I just want to make sure if available openssl command line does not have such thing. Thanks!

Comment: openssl command line does have a diagnostic utility to check SSL connections called [s_client](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/s_client.html).

Answer (score 0):

The system (PKI) just doesn't work like this. You would have to launch your own certificate management system -- purchase a sub-CA certificate from existing CA, then start issuing your certificates. Next, your scheme with giving a PIN to the user is insecure and the CA won't sell you the sub-CA certificate after reviewing it.

In general your task requires solid understanding of how PKI works and of security backgrounds. So the question is too broad for StackOverflow.